# 0,1-Tree, number of branches

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, trees, infinitary-combinatorics

How many branches has this tree:
$\{s\in 2^{<\kappa}:|\alpha\in dom(s):s(\alpha)\neq 0|<\aleph_0\}$,
and why? How does the tree look like, i.e. what is its shape? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "path" in this context? Totally ordered subset? Maximal totally ordered subset?

Comment: Maximal linearly (=totally) ordered subset.

Comment: Also, based on the notation, it seems that you're dealing with the set of binary functions with finite [support](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) having as domain some ordinal less than $\kappa.$ is this correct? I assume that the order relation is simply $\subseteq$?

Comment: Yes the relation is $\subseteq$.What do you mean by the support?

Comment: Sorry about that. The link is fixed now. Maximal linearly ordered subsets of trees are often called "branches."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this tree will look sort of like the full binary tree $2^{<\kappa}$, except that all of the nodes with infinitely many $1$s are missing.  Let's call your tree $T$.  Then every branch of $T$ can be extended to a branch of $2^{<\kappa}$, i.e. a function $\kappa\to 2$.  But given a function $\kappa\to 2$, not all of its restrictions will be elements of $T$: only those with only finitely many $1$s.  That is, the restriction forgets about all of the values of the function $\kappa\to 2$ after the first $\omega$ $1$s.

Thus the branches of $T$ are in bijection with subsets $S$ of $\kappa$ of order type $\leq\omega$.  Explicitly, given such a subset $S$, you get a branch by taking all initial segments of the characteristic function of $S$ prior to the supremum of its first $\omega$ elements.  Conversely, given a branch $B$, the union of all the elements of $B$ is a function $f:\alpha\to 2$ for some $\alpha\leq\kappa$.  If $\alpha<\kappa$, the fact that $B$ cannot be extended by adding $f$ as another member means that $f$ takes the value $1$, which means $f$ is the characteristic function of a cofinal subset of $\alpha$ of order-type $\omega$.  If $\alpha=\kappa$, then $f$ must similarly be either the characteristic function of a finite subset of $\kappa$ or the characteristic function of a cofinal subset of $\kappa$ of order-type $\omega$.  Combining all the cases together, $f$ comes from a subset of $\kappa$ of order-type $\leq\omega$.

Let us now count how many branches there are (assuming $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal).  There are $\kappa$ finite subsets of $\kappa$.  The elements of a subset of order-type $\omega$ can be chosen one-by-one in increasing order, and at each step you have $\kappa$ choices (there are still $\kappa$ elements greater than the last one you chose).  So there are $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ subsets of order-type $\omega$.  In total, then, there are $\kappa+\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ branches.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. There is a book by Kenneth Kunen Introduction to independence proofs who states on page 214 "...or with exactly $\kappa$ paths (such as $\{s\in 2^{<\kappa}:|\alpha\in dom(s):s(\alpha)\neq 0|<\aleph_0\}$). But $\kappa$-trees with more than $\kappa$ paths, first studied by Kurepa, are non-trivial." So his result is $\kappa$ paths not $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ I've tried to send you the book to your email, but returned error occurs.

Comment: It's possible that in context he means to be assuming that $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$.  You can email me at (my name) at gmail.

Comment: Sent. I do not see such an assumption.

Comment: @user122424: What is $\kappa,$ in the given context? A cardinal, if I recall correctly, but are there any other assumptions made about it?

Comment: This is the problem. It is an infinite cardinal, but in the Kunen's book it is not assumed that $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$ as needed by the result of Wofsey.